# getting ripples while selecting with stylus after installing window 10

Tags: customization, selection-tools, drivers

I installed window 10 yesterday, as well as the wacom driver (the tablet was not responding), and verified the settings. Now I cannot select (everything was fine before, Rclick mapped to stylus button) anymore, I  get  some ripple effect around the cursor and it doesn't select.

Comment: This is for W7 but might work on W10: http://www.volnapc.com/all-posts/how-to-get-rid-of-those-annoying-circles-from-your-wacom-cursor-in-windows-7

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Windows 10/Wacom input drivers.